# ADF - problem adding a second list to a binding xml page

Tags: list, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

Jdev V 12.2.1.4.0

we're experiencing a strange problem that we can't solve.

we have an ADF page with a template, menu, and a few JSFF fragments.

some of the JSFF pages have list binding components with beta data source = variable, and dynamic list when the "no selection" item is set to blank (first line).

so far it's working ok, we do get a blank field on the first selection for those lists on every JSFF page that has a list component (select one choice).

However, we got to the point that adding another list (a component on the JSFF page, or a list on the binding page without any appearance on the JSFF page led to the first line of those 'existing/ working/ lists' which i mentioned above, to appear as . in addition, on one of our JSFF pages we use a master-detail table, the query stopped returning results even if we choose an item that is NOT the first  item all of that after adding a second list to the JSFF page that is linked to the binding xml page.

when we undo the change (of the new list addon ), the existing list's first line shows a blank first item like it was before. on the the Master-Details JSFF page, the undo lead to the master-details query to work fine.

this behavior (the  appearance) happens only on the JSFF page which the new list was added to and does not affect the other JSFF page that also has a list, we still see the blank item as it was before on those other pages that we did not add a new list to its binding page (XXXPageDef.xml)

we don't understand what can be the reason of adding a new list (which can be a dynamic list or a simple static list ) that leads to this issue

and mote how to solve this..
p.s- we dont know if its related to the actual addon of the second list, or the project itself has somekind of another problem/ conflict which caused all of this

Comment: However, we got to the point that adding another list (a component on the JSFF page, or a list on the binding page without any appearance on the JSFF page led to the first line of those 'existing/ working/ lists' which i mentioned above, to appear as "<NULL>"